# Reconstructing absolute urls from relative urls on a page

Tags: python, html, url-parsing

Given an absolute url of a page, and a relative link found within that page, would there be a way to **a)** definitively reconstruct or **b)** best-effort reconstruct the absolute url of the relative link?

In my case, I'm reading an html file from a given url using beautiful soup, stripping out all the img tag sources, and trying to construct a list of absolute urls to the page images.

My Python function so far looks like:

```
function get_image_url(page_url,image_src):

    from urlparse import urlparse
    # parsed = urlparse('http://user:pass@NetLoc:80/path;parameters?query=argument#fragment')
    parsed = urlparse(page_url)
    url_base = parsed.netloc
    url_path = parsed.path

    if src.find('http') == 0:
        # It's an absolute URL, do nothing.
        pass
    elif src.find('/') == 0:
        # If it's a root URL, append it to the base URL:
        src = 'http://' + url_base + src
    else:
        # If it's a relative URL, ?
```

**NOTE:** Don't need a Python answer, just the logic required.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

very simple:

```
>>> from urlparse import urljoin
>>> urljoin('http://mysite.com/foo/bar/x.html', '../../images/img.png')
'http://mysite.com/images/img.png'
```

Comment: Hey coool!! (Guess I did need Python..)

Comment: The urlparse module is renamed to urllib.parse in Python 3. So, `from urllib.parse import urljoin`

Answer (score 20):

Use [`urllib.parse.urljoin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin) to resolve a (possibly relative) URL against a base URL.

*But*, the base URL of a web page isn't necessarily the same as the URL you fetched the document from, because HTML allows a page to specify its preferred base URL [via the `BASE` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-base-element). The logic you need is as follows:

```
base_url = page_url
head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
for base in head.getElementsByTagName('base'):
    if base.hasAttribute('href'):
        base_url = urllib.parse.urljoin(base_url, base.getAttribute('href'))
        # HTML5 4.2.3 "if there are multiple base elements with href
        # attributes, all but the first are ignored."
        break
```

(If you are parsing XHTML then in theory you ought to take into account the rather hairy [XML Base specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlbase/) instead. But you can probably get away without worrying about that, since no-one really uses XHTML.)